# How to connect to an AS/400 system from a chrome (or other) browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, ibm-midrange

I would need to connect to a database that is in a AS/400 system using just a browser, at least in Chrome, but without any plugins/extensions.

If it's possible you may post a link to a page or show an example of how to implement it. I've been searching on Google but no luck :s

### Update:

Even using some plugins/extensions is not possible?

Thanks (:

Comment: Ask the administrator of the AS/400 how.  It's not likely possible though.

Comment: "using just a browser" ... you want to display a "phpmyadmin"-like interface that will allow you administrating your databse ?

Comment: @Don Roby: the admin doesn't know.

Comment: @Zakaria: not exactly, I just want an application that shows the stocks of the articles we have, something very simple.

Comment: @Totty - I _think_ there's a plugin/setting for Excel, that can grab data from the AS/400.  Have it talk to a user with access to only views of the queries you want.  If you want this _externally_ available (ie, for 'customers'), you will **NEED** to create a webservice, with full-on security, etc (security especially).

Comment: The Excel add-on is licensed software - part of Client Access I believe.

Comment: In excel and access I can easily get the data, but I would like to do it in a browser if possible..

Comment: @Totty, if your question is if Chrome has an DB2 Data Connector built-in, then, the answer is no.

Comment: @Totty, if your question is if Chrome has built-in a feature to show the stocks of your articles, then, the answer is, obiously, not.

Comment: of course I'm not thinking that chrome comes with a built in feature to show the stocks lol but it might have a feature to connect to and odbc, or to a db2 server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No web browser can connect to a remote database directly, unless the DBMS happens to support HTTP (if there are any, I'm not aware of them). Browsers use HTTP for network communications. DBMSs use their own proprietary protocols. To use a browser to access a database, you need some sort of intermediary server on the computer hosting the database that bridges between HTTP and the DBMS.

Answer (score 3):

You need a database driver to talk to a database (otherwise you need to speak the native API yourself).  I am unaware of such a thing for DB2/400 for Javascript.

Have you considered running a web server on the AS/400 which know how to get the data you need and then just invoke that instead?

Comment: There are 2 main problems: I don't really have full access to the system and I don't really know how to do such things.. Currently we have an MsAccess app that uses an ODBC driver to get data, but access is too bad and limited to do what we need.

Comment: If you have ODBC running (which essentially is an SQL tunnel), you can use that with other applications too, like Excel or OpenOffice Base.    Perhaps you would like to open a new question about what you need your application to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's potentially possible using Net.Data. It might not be viable for many years in the future, but it should already be available on your server if you have the basic web server product installed. All the work is done by configuring a web server instance and coding the Net.Data scripts/macros on your AS/400.

And if you only want a few lists that can be generated through basic SQL statements, then Net.Data is all that's needed. No browser plug-ins, no addition products on the server or the PC. No ODBC or JDBC drivers. Not even any "programming" needed outside of coding the scripts and macros. Just a plain browser.

You **can** create as much support programming as you wish. It just doesn't seem needed for this question.

Comment: I don't think OP can write code on the IBM i side but if he could, Net.Data is a useful way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, do this using a browser plugin. 
However you'd likely need to write it yourself.

Comment: do you think that someone without knowledge of the matter can do it in 1 week? (both as400 linkage and chrome extension)

Comment: @Totty - probably not, although you should be able to use the JDBC plugin (Toolbox) for Java.  However, this is _extremely_ insecure.

Comment: Why would that be _extremely_ insecure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it is a good thing to access the DB directly from JavaScript. Like others allready wrote, you should consider using a web server, but there is possibly no need to install anything on the AS/400 to do that, as long as you have some way to connect to the database (via JDBC or maybe ODBC), and that you'll need anyway to connect to it.

So you can install your web server (apache or whatever) on any server (e.g. a Linux box) that can access the AS/400s DB. Then write some web pages in Java or PHP or whatever. You could either display some HTML directly, or create some kind of ajax interface, that is operated by your JavaScript from your browser.

I don't think there are many sysadmins that would support a setup where your browser communicates with the DB directly. But if you have some (web-)server side programs, that control access via username/password and session or such, and then supply information via ajax or html you have a pretty common setup.

Everything that runs in JavaScript in a browser runs *on the client's computer*. So the access information to the database must be present in the browser on the client's computer, outside of every control of you. There is no way of stopping them from sending any SQL-Query they want. And if you want your program to update data in the DB, than you can imagin, what kind of trust you need in the device the browser runs in. Even if only members of your firm use your JavaScript program, that would still be a bad idea since you should never trust a browser that much (there are several ways a third party web site could try to gain access to that JavaScript program). And you would most likely be transfering your log in credentials for your DB to and from the browser running device many times (even using https I'd think that's a design flaw).